# Default image is not displaying while profile imageis null in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4. I want to display a default profile image if the profile image is `null`.

In my scenario the profile image is displaying correctly, but it's not displaying the default image if the user hasn't uploaded it.

My code is:

```
field: 'image',
title: '',                       
width: 50,

template: function (row, index, datatable) {
    if (image != "") {
        return '\<img src="' + row.image+ '" />';
    }
    else {
        return '\<img src="/src/assets/images/image.png"/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try `image` in the condition

```
template: function (row, index, datatable) {
     return image ? '\<img src="' + row.image+ '" />' :
                    '\<img src="/src/assets/images/image.png"/>';
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking wwhether an image is not equal to "", to check null just do,

```
if (image != "") {
      return '\<img src="' + row.image+ '" />';
}
else if (!image || image == ""){
    return '\<img src="/src/assets/images/image.png"/>';
}
```